# FFMPEG with PHP does not execute?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, thumbnails

After reading about a gazillion questions here on SO related to FFMPEG with PHP I have gotten together a small snippet or what-not, but it does not seem to do anything - not even throw errors.

My PHP is as follows:

```
function get_video_thumbnail($file) {
    define('ALL_PLACE_WIDTH', 250);
    define('ALL_PLACE_HEIGHT', 200);

    $ffmpeg = "ffmpeg"; // where ffmpeg is
    $image_source_path = $file; // where the video is
    $image_cmd = " -r 1 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:01 -s ".ALL_PLACE_WIDTH."x".ALL_PLACE_HEIGHT."   -f image2 "; // command
    $dest_image_path = "cdn/thumbnails"; // destination of thumbnail

    $str_command = $ffmpeg  ." -i " . $image_source_path . $image_cmd .$dest_image_path;     
    shell_exec($str_command);
}
```

in the root folder there's a folder "ffmpeg" in what there's "ffmpeg.exe", "ffplay.exe" and "pthreadGC2.dll". So I'm wondering, is there anything I'm missing? I'm trying to generate a thumbnail from a video/mp4 file.

Comment: If you run the same parameters from the command line do you produce a thumbnail?

If you run `exec(escapeshellcmd($cmd), $out, $val)` what do you see in the outputs $out and $val?

Break it down - first try executing a simplified version first to find out if ffmpeg is working when called through the PHP shell. e.g. `'ffmpeg -h'`

Comment: this is how i do it: $exec_string = "ffmpeg -y -ss ".($position)." -i $filebase.mpg -vf scale='iw:ow/dar',setsar=1:1  -deinterlace -t 1 $output_base";     its pretty weird that you set -t before -ss, it should be -t 11

Comment: There are other ways to execute external commands with more control over their environment and output: [`exec`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and [`proc_open`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php). Append `2>&1` to the command, invoke it through `exec`, capture and print the output, inspect it for any error messages...

Answer (score 0):

Is cdn/thumbnails a folder? If so you have to give the file name. You have only given a folder. Hence it does not work.  Since you want one every second for 10 seconds you have to give something like cdn/thumbnails/images%03d.jpg as the output.

So your command will look something like this:

ffmpeg -i inputfile -s widthxheight -f image2 folder/filename%04d.jpg

Go to the command line and first type out the command. Ensure it works there. Then it will work from php.

the files will be named filename0000.jpg filename0001.jpg and so on.